# Graphing $x^2+y^2=\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was given the following equation to graph.
$$x^2+y^2=\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$$
Entering it in Desmos produces a four-leaf clover.

However, I'm wondering how one can deduce its shape logically. For instance, the equation $y=2(x-3)^2 + 6$ can be formed by transformations of $y=x^2$.

The left side of the equation would be part of a circle equation and the right side would be a rotated square. I don't see how combining the two would produce that graph, but maybe there's a different way? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A four-leaf clover, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=x+y$ is a circle.

In $x^2+y^2=\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$, the equation $x^2+y^2=x+y$ only holds when $x\ge0, y\ge0$, and so the circle gets cut into a petal.

The other three petals come from the considering the other quadrants.

Comment: Actually the graph also includes the origin, $|x|=x$ for all _nonnegative_ real $x$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, good point. Desmos fails to show the origin.